# PHP update textbox when value of dropdown is changed

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I filled my dropdown menu with data from the database. I can select here the name of the product. I have a second textbox on my page. Here i want to show the price of the selected product. I tried different ways but I o net get it working.

First of all this is my dropdown menu where the product name is showed:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM form";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' style='width: 100%;'>";
     echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<option onchange='OnChange()' value='" . $row["id"]. "'>" . $row["name"]. "</option>";
     }                   
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

I want to show the price of the selected value in this textbox:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbsi";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT price FROM form WHERE id='". $product1 ."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='price1' id='price1' onkeyup='getValues()' value='" . $row["price1"]. "'>";


     }                   
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Using this script i only get "0 results" in price1. It doesnt update when i change the selected value of the dropdown menu. How can I ensure that price1 gets updated when i select another value in the dropdown menu?

**Update 1:**
I tried to add the the following script

```
<script>
function OnChange(){
  UpdatePoints(<?php echo $price1; ?>);
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.onchange=load; </script>";
</script>
```

When I use this script i still get "0 results"

**Update 2:**
The following is still not working:

```
//filename: test.php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forms";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' onChange='getstate(this.value);' style='width: 100%;'>";
     echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $row["id"]. "'>" . $row["name"]. "</option>";
     }                   
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forms WHERE id='". $product1 ."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          echo "<div id='price-list'>";
              echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='price1' id='price1' value='" . $row["price"]. "'>";
          echo "</div>";

     }                   
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>  

<script>
         function getprice(val) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "test.php",
              data:'id='+val,
              success: function(data){
                $("#price-list").html(data);
              }
            });
          }
</script>

<?php
$product1=$_POST['price1'];
?>
```

Comment: where'd you get `$row["price1"]` index, you didn't select a column with that name, maybe you mean just `$row["price"]`, or is this just a typo of some sort

Comment: and just make sure the php page has a proper form with submit buttons and stuff, and `$product1` is undefined in the second code block

Comment: You can use ajax or javascript `on_load()` to automatically load the value into the textbox when the dropdown select change.

Comment: I use `$row["price1"]` for calculations. The calculations are working fine.

Comment: I tried `code`<script>
function OnLoad(){
  UpdatePoints(<?php echo $price1; ?>);
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.onload=load; </script>";
</script>`code` but this doesnt work @rhavendc

Comment: You have to use ajax and jquery  onchange get the value from drop down and with that value select from the price

Comment: @John oh pardon me for giving you a wrong event syntax. It's `onchange`, not `on_load`. @ArunKumaresh was right.

Comment: I add `onchange='OnChange()'` to the dropdown menu (product1). I changed the script in `<script>
function OnChange(){
  UpdatePoints(<?php echo $price1; ?>);
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.onchange=load; </script>";
</script>`. I still get "0 results" @ArunKumaresh

Comment: on change you have use the ajax call and get the value of the drop down

Comment: Do you have a example for me? I cant find anything on the internet. @ArunKumaresh

Comment: check my answer and accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
make a ajax call and get the value of using post   

 <script>
         function getprice(val) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "index.php",
              data:'priceid='+val,
              success: function(data){
                $("#price-list").html(data);
              }
            });
          }
    </script>

    <select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' style='width: 100%;'  onChange="getstate(this.value);">
    //yourcode
    </select>

    <div id="price-list">
    </div>



index.php
<?php
$product1=$_POST['priceid'];
?>
```

Comment: Still get "0 results". See `Update 2`.

Comment: what you have tired post the entire code where did you make ajax call

Comment: @John : pls make sure $sql = "SELECT * FROM forms WHERE id='". $product1 ."'"; is creating correct
And also do not forgot to concat the price1 field if there are more than one

Comment: When I send $product1 to the database it sends the ID. The query `SELECT * FROM forms WHERE id = '1'` is working. To be sure I tested it like `SELECT * FROM forms WHERE name='. $product1 .'` but the result is the same @sinto

Comment: This is the Ajax call, right? `<script>
         function getprice(val) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "test.php",
              data:'id='+val,
              success: function(data){
                $("#price-list").html(data);
              }
            });
          }
</script>` This is at the bottom of the page @ArunKumaresh

Comment: post entire code what you have tried then only i can find error in it

Comment: what does the test.php contains

Comment: `test.php` is the page where the code is (same page) @ArunKumaresh

Comment: it containts the code that is written at **Update 2**

Comment: you second part of the code should contain in a separate file named test.php and your first part of the code should present in the another page since your are using a ajax call where path is specified as test.php

Comment: Witch part of the code do i need to separate from the current code? Is it possible to use this script without separating? @ArunKumaresh

Comment: I want to show the price in the textbox called: `price1`

This is the textbox price1 `echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='price1' id='price1' value='" . $row["price"]. "'>";` @ArunKumaresh